# JQueryMobile and Rails redirect_to not executing javascript inside page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I am having a troublesome issue with my rails app. I'm using jquerymobile and my difficulties started when I wanted to make a landing page that divides the screen into 4 equal sections.  If you visit www.kiwilive.com you will see what I mean.

Here's how I recreate the problem.

Go to www.kiwilive.com - everything should look good.  This is the 'new' action of my tempusers controller. The windows are sized with the following javascript

```js
$(document).on('pageshow', function (event, ui) { 
windowHeight = $(window).height();
windowWidth = $(window).width();
divHeight = (windowHeight)/2; // heights of your header/footer
$('#splash_logo').css({width: "50%", height: divHeight+"px"});
$('#splash_speechBubble').css({width: "50%", height: divHeight+"px"});
$('#splash_mobileIcon').css({width: "50%", height: divHeight+"px"});
$('#splash_mailIcon').css({width: "50%", height: divHeight+"px"});
});
```

Type 'jeff' into the input box.

Click the second button 'Start my kiwi'.

Since the 'jeff' keyword is already taken, the controller should display a flash message and redirect to root_path via this code (which is definitely getting called)

```
flash[:alert] = "Your kiwi is already being used.  Please try a different word!"
redirect_to root_path and return
```

However, after the redirect happens, I cannot get the javascript to rerun so the sizing of the windows goes haywire.

My searching revealed that I should try to use the 'pageshow' event for JQM. It still doesn't work. Also, my 'script' tags do seem to be within my page element as follows from my application.html.erb file:

```html
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="mainpage" data-theme="b" data-url="<%= request.fullpath%>"> 
<% if flash.count > 0 %>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
          <%= value %></div>
  <%end%>
<%else%>
<%end%>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %> 
</div>
</body>
```

I am out of ideas and all sorts of searching hasn't turned up anything. Please help!
Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured out my own question.
It looks like JQueryMobile, upon an ajax request, just keeps adding the same page to the DOM without removing the previous page. So you need to specify that you're applying styling to the elements on the active page, otherwise it will get confused (i.e. multiple divs with the same name!).  My code works by substituting

```
$('#splash_logo').css({width: "50%", height: divHeight+"px"});
```

with

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('#splash_logo')
```

I hope this helps someone else.  Took me forever to get figured out.